# how to wait for some flags to change

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, .net-4.5

I'm writing an app for windows phone 8 which for loading it's contents, should load and parse some data form some file. The loading and parsing part happens in three different async tasks and when each task is finished, a public Boolean flag changes from false to true. All this takes at most about a second or two and the data is vital for the app's run-time, so I have put it in a `SplashScreen.xaml`'s `OnNavigatedTo` method. Now I want to know how can I wait for all n flags to become true so that I can proceed to the main page safely.

Thank you all.

Comment: If the Tasks are awaited, why would you need the flags?

Comment: Because the call is a not awaited, I have to call them in the `OnNavigatedTo` method which is not async.(Unfortunately I know very little about threading and tasks and that's why I came up with keeping the flags idea...!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have tasks, you can use the method `Task.WhenAll` to execute an action when all tasks are done executing:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Note: The navigation can be called only from the UI thread. The `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` parameter captures the current synchronization context, but it will work only if you call the `Task.WhenAll` method from the UI thread. Otherwise, you'll have to use the dispatcher:

```
Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
});
```